# Subset data frame 1 using data frame 2 without knowing columns in data frame 2 in advance

Tags: r, subset

I have two data frames:

```
x <- data.frame(A1 = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2), A2 = c(1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2), value = 1:8)
y <- data.frame(A1 = 2, A2 = 2)
x
y
```

I need to select rows from x that have values on A1 and A2 specified in y (in this case, rows 7 and 8).

However, I don't know in advance, how many columns that start with an "A" I will have. It could be just one (A1) or several (A1, A2, A3, etc.)
Important: x and y always have the same columns that start with an "A" and y always has only ONE row.

I can get what I want using a loop:

```
out <- x
y_columns <- names(y)
for(i in y_columns) out <- out[out[[i]] == y[[i]],]
out
```

Is there a more elegant way of achieving my objective?

Thank you very much!

Comment: `merge(x, y)` Use merge with keys as A1 and A2, so basically whatever column they have in match it would yield the corresponding rows, I hope I understood you well

Comment: Thank you! Of course!!

Comment: Can you put it as an answer? I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

`merge(x, y)` can work here, let us break it down further, so the functions says:

```
merge(x, y, by = intersect(names(x), names(y)),
      by.x = by, by.y = by, all = FALSE, all.x = all, all.y = all,
      sort = TRUE, suffixes = c(".x",".y"), no.dups = TRUE,
      incomparables = NULL, ...)
```

here, the by parameter is basically intersection of column names of two tables, in this case it will be A1 and A2. However, if there are multiple rows in parent/lookup table, it will return multiple records.

here, `merge(x, y)` returns

```
 A1 A2 value
1  2  2     7
2  2  2     8
```